# Shared Hosting with MongoDB installed

Tags: mongodb, shared-hosting

Are there any Shared Hosting that has MongoDB installed?

Thanks

Comment: Not that I have seen. You can check a list of DaaS & PaaS services here and pick one though. http://www.cloudhostingguru.com/mongoDB-server-hosting.php

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of MongoDB as a service companies out there, and almost all have free instances.  Checkout [MongoHQ](http://mongohq.com/)

Connecting to a shared hosting instance would be no more complicated than at a MongoDB service, and you'll get much better support and tools from a service.